# A tool for checking broken web links

Tags: software-rec, web

Please recommend a tool that checks for broken links on a web site.

**not required, but would be nice to have**:

- checks standards-compliance of the HTML, CSS, Javascript, ...
- displays permanent redirects

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[LinkChecker](http://linkchecker.github.io/linkchecker/).

> LinkChecker is a free, GPL licensed URL validator.
>
> **Features**
>
> - recursive and multithreaded checking
> - output in colored or normal text, HTML, SQL, CSV, XML or a sitemap graph in different formats
> - HTTP/1.1, HTTPS, FTP, mailto:, news:, nntp:, Telnet and local file links support
> - restriction of link checking with regular expression filters for URLs
> - proxy support
> - username/password authorization for HTTP and FTP and Telnet
> - honors robots.txt exclusion protocol
> - Cookie support
> - HTML and CSS syntax check
> - Antivirus check
> - Different interfaces: command line, GUI and web interface

It's also in Debian Lenny: `aptitude install linkchecker` and in the FreeBSD ports: `/usr/ports/www/linkchecker`

Comment: That's a great tool! I find it very useful to validate the links in my project. Thanks to both!

Comment: Why add a note about Lenny? Here, we are trying to keep things generic, if we can help it.

Comment: @Tshepang: Because I'm trying to be useful. Does it bother anyone? Stop being pedantic, please.

Comment: @andre It only makes sense if I mentioned in my question "Which tool can I use for checking broken web links in Debian Lenny"? And, if someone doesn't know how to find how to install it, they can always ask "How do I install linkchecker in Debian Lenny". Sorry if I come across as pedantic.

Comment: @Tshepang: I disagree. I think it's a useful note that doesn't take away from anyone else - the source is still in the first link. Having said that, if a moderator asks me to remove it I will do so.

Comment: Note that wummel stopped development of LinkChecker in 2016. Active development continues in the [linkchecker/linkchecker](https://github.com/linkchecker/linkchecker) repo. Unfortunately, Google still (as of late 2020) returns the old wummel repo as the first hit if you search for LinkChecker.